# Sharing Webpage to Social Network from Firefox

Tags: firefox, desktop, social-networking

Firefox for Android allows me to quickly share the current page on facebook and other social networks. Is there any such option on Firefox for Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarklets might be an option for you:

http://www.facebook.com/share_options.php

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/share-bookmarklet

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend installing an add-on, firefox has so many awesome ones!

Add-this is a good one, adds a quick way to share directly from firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/addthis/

There are lots of other options, so search and find one which suits your sharing style.
 Hope that helps!

Good luck and may the force be with you.

Nate